# Why is the plus sign stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c, if-statement, infinite-loop

So my goal is to build a ruler in c code and I'm stuck I don't know why it's duplicating after 5 it's suppose to go back to printing dashes here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    int length;
    int count;
    int num;

    length = 0;
    while(length > -1)
    {
        printf("Please enter a length (-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        for (count = 1; count <= length; count++)
            if (count <5)
                printf("-");
            else if (count = 5)
                printf("+");
            else if (( count > 6 ) && (count < 10))
                printf("-");

        printf("\n");
    }

}

int double_digit(int g){
    int dubl=0;

    while(g>0){
        int digit = g % 10;
        if (digit < 5) {
            digit *= 2;
        } else {
            digit = 9;
        }
        dubl = dubl * 10 + digit;
        g /= 10;
    }
    printf("%d\n", dubl);
}
```

Comment: `count = 5` is an assignment. Use `if (count == 5)`.

Comment: `else if (count = 5)` assigns 5 to `count` and once that happens it is always true. Use `==` to compare values.

Comment: When count == 6 you won't get any character printed.

Comment: Sidenote: When you've fixed the typo, it'll still be very confusing for the user of the program since it will only print max 8 characters, like this: `----+---` because of the `count < 10` condition.

Answer (score 2):

`else if(count = 5)` assigns 5 to the variable count. You're looking for the Boolean expression `else if(count == 5)`

Comment: Don't post an answer for a simple typo like this. The question should just be closed after comments explain it to the poster.

Comment: I can't comment until 50 Rep :(

Comment: I know. But other people already commented the same thing, your answer is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you im kicking myself haha